# Replace character with windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace, character

I get from a FOR loop a variable with drive locations, something like this:

`c:\test1`
`c:\test2`
`d:\test3` ...and so on

I need to change the `c:` to `c$` so I can map a network drive with the net use

`net use k: \\machine\c$\test\`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
set TEST=c:\test

REM set NEW_TEST=%TEST:x=y%
```

x is what you want to replace (can be a character or a string)
y is what you want to replace with (can be a character or a string)

Wilds can be used (*)

```
set NEW_TEST=%TEST:x=y%

echo %NEW_TEST%
```

c$\test